# How sensitive is a site's UUID?

Tags: 8, security, entities

I have set up continuous integration for a Drupal site. After every `git push` the site is built remotely from scratch in a Docker container. It runs a site install, sets the site's UUID to import the configs, creates some sample content and then runs Behat tests.

For simplicity I'd simply commit the UUID in a text file and then import it like so:

```
drush cset system.site uuid "$(< sites/default/uuid.txt)"
```

The underlying question I have is if it's OK – from a security point of perspective - to commit a site's UUID into a public Git repo? Does that create any vulnerabilities to my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, only after I created the question it came to my mind that the UUID itself already may be present inside a config YAML. And indeed it is. Inside `system.site.yml`. So, I guess when it's OK to have it printed inside a config YAML – with the purpose to get version tracked – it's no problem to have it inside a text file as well.

Comment: I guess the only difference being that most web servers will be default-configured to allow the contents of txt files to be served, but not yml files. So there's probably still a slight security concern for some people